# ListView with CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE using CheckedText in a custom view

Tags: android

There are plenty of questions of how to use `CheckedTextView` but I can't make it work correctly.

I have a `CursorAdapter` with a custom view which has a `CheckedTextView` with `android:id="@android:id/text1"`. I have used `android:id/text1` because there are different questions that mention that if you use it you will get the choice mode multiple for free.

If I do something like this:

```
final long[] checkedIds = mListView.getCheckedItemIds();
for ( int i = 0 ; i < mListView.getCheckedItemCount() ; i++ ) {
    Log.d(TAG, "id checked: " + checkedIds[i]);
}
```

I get all the checked ids without an issue, but I can't see any visual feedback in the `ListView`.

In other words the logic is fine but when I click the `CheckedTextView` The green tick doesn't show up.

I was reading the `ListView` src code and I couldn't find any reference to `android:id/text1` and makes me wonder if I should handle widget's checked state myself.

Can anyone spot where `android:id/text1` is used to make the widget checked or not?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Based on my read of the code, the row has to implement `Checkable`:

```
if (mChoiceMode != CHOICE_MODE_NONE && mCheckStates != null) {
    if (child instanceof Checkable) {
        ((Checkable) child).setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position));
    }
}
```

This works for the stock row layouts for lists with choice mode because the row is a `CheckedTextView`, which implements `Checkable`.

So, add the `Checkable` interface to your custom `View`, delegating the interface's methods to the `CheckedTextView`, and see if that works out.

Comment: Cool. That's what I did. I did a custom view which extends `LinearLayout` and implements `Checkable`. Using `android:id/text1` is not necessary, you just need your parent view to be checkable. I am now getting duplicated green ticks but that's a different problem.

Thanks, Mark!

Comment: what if i have radiobutton in base adapter?