# How to delete multiple selected line items from a listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, null, nullpointerexception

I have implemented a simple method to delete multiple items from a listview following this solution [Removing muliple items from listview using Check box in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715556/removing-muliple-items-from-listview-using-check-box-in-android), then modified it a small bit to allow for a switch statement for the two button click events, `add` & `delete`.But the problem is when I click the delete button the app crashes giving me these errors: http://pastebin.com/2NmCQk2B

I'm not sure why I'm getting the null pointer exception as I believe I have assigned everything correctly.

Can someone better explain why I could be getting this error? Or perhaps a better way of deleting selected line items from a listview?

The complete class is posted below for better understanding:

```
public class TopRatedFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    ListView mListView;
    EditText mValue;
    Button mAdd,mDel;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates ;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, container, false);
         mAdd = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.newList);
         mDel = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.delBtn);
         mAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
         mDel.setOnClickListener(this);
         mValue = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listData);
         adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, list);

    // set the lv variable to your list in the xml
         mListView=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);  
         mListView.setAdapter(adapter);


        return rootView;    
    }


    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.newList:
             //DO something
            String input = mValue.getText().toString();
            if(input.length() > 0)
            {
                // add string to the adapter, not the listview
                adapter.add(input);
                // no need to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); as it is done by the adapter.add() method
            }
        break;
        case R.id.delBtn:
             //DO something
            SparseBooleanArray checked = mListView.getCheckedItemPositions();
            for (int i = 0; i < mListView.getCount(); i++){

                //line 65
                if (checked.get(i)==true)
                {
                     list.remove(i);

                } 
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

            }
             mListView.clearChoices();               
        }


    }   

}
```

[image: Listview/Interface]

Comment: this ` if (checked.get(i)==true)`

Comment: how do you populate list. i guess its empty

Comment: I populate list by entering items in edittext and clicking add button

Comment: can you log `mListView.getCount();` and check the count??

Comment: yes,How do I do that? just log.e?

Comment: First thing is to see is that your "checked" variable is null. Figure out why it´s null and then you´ll have something going. If you can´t figure out why "getCheckItemPositions" returns null, have a read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402150/getcheckeditempositions-always-returning-null-android-listview , also, be absolutely sure to NOT HAVE choice mode in ListView set to CHOICE_MODE_NONE.

Comment: I just noticed that this listview does not include check boxes so this is probably why it is crashing because null pointer.How can I make the listview include checkboxes?

Comment: I have added a screen shot of the interface,you see there is no check boxes,how do I make the listview with checkboxes?

Comment: @BrianJ `listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);`

Comment: @Raghunandan so it would just be mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE); and then the listview will includes `checks`?

Comment: @BrianJ yup . that should work

Comment: @Raghunandan is there a simple way to have the text item be striked through when the checkbox is ticked?

Comment: Reverse the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use valueAt(), the working code should be

```
SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = mListView.getCheckedItemPositions();
if (checkedItems != null) {
    for (int i=0; i<checkedItems.size(); i++) {
        if (checkedItems.valueAt(i)) {
            String item = mListView.getAdapter().getItem(
                                  checkedItems.keyAt(i)).toString();
            Log.i(TAG,item + " was selected");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove from adapter instead from listview try following:

```
 SparseBooleanArray checked = mListView.getCheckedItemPositions();

  if(checked!=null){
  for (int i = 0; i < mListView.getCount(); i++){

            //line 65
            if (checked.get(i)==true)
            {
                 adapter.remove(mListView.getItemAtPosition(i));

            } 
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

        }
         mListView.clearChoices(); 
   }
```

getCheckedItemPositions Returns:
A SparseBooleanArray which will return true for each call to get(int position) where position is a checked position in the list and false otherwise, or null if the choice mode is set to CHOICE_MODE_NONE.

Comment: why would `if (checked.get(i)==true)` line 65 throw NPE??

Comment: check for null before for loop

Comment: Reverse the for loop: start at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I used loop this way, and it worked:

```
SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
                int itemCount = getListView().getCount();

                for(int i=itemCount-1; i >= 0; i--){
                    if(checkedItemPositions.get(i)){
                        adapter.remove(list.get(i));
                    }
                }
                checkedItemPositions.clear();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```