# CheckedTextView doesn't respond to click

Tags: android, android-layout, checked, checkedtextview

I have a listview that is dynamically populated with CheckedTextViews. The listview is set to multiple choice mode. I'm using OnItemClickListener to respond to clicks on my listview. Also I made an XML file with CheckedTextView's layout (actually it is just a copy of standard android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice). So in this case all works fine: when I'm clicking an item in the listview, the appropriate checkedtextview becomes checked. But when I'm trying to use the following layout, the checkedtextview doesn't respond to the click and still unchecked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:orientation="vertical"  
    android:padding="5px">
    <CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingRight="6dip"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I guess that it because CheckedTextViews are put into LinearLayout and they don't receive the click event from list items of the Listview.

Answer (score 1):

<del>I guess different. If you look at the [source code of `simple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml`](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml&q=package:android%20simple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml&type=cs), you'll see an `android:checkMark` attribute set to `?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple`. This is what the `CheckedTextView` internally uses to draw the check box in whatever state it happens to be, as you may be able to see from [its source code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/CheckedTextView.java&q=package:android%20checkedtextview&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc).</del>

<del>But the definition of `CheckedTextView` in your layout lacks this attribute. This I would blame, rather than the use of `CheckedTextView` in a `LinearLayout` element.</del>

I was wrong and you guessed right. It seems that the row for the custom `ListView` needs to implement `Checkable`, which `CheckedTextView` does but `LinearLayout` does not. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612600/listview-with-choice-mode-multiple-using-checkedtext-in-a-custom-view/5612808#5612808) in another StackOverflow thread for details.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, so I changed the layout to android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice instead of using a custom layout with a CheckedTextView.

Answer (score 0):

Well even if they don't receive the OnClickEvent you can maintain the state of these checkboxes using a boolean ArrayList of same size of List Items. [Here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818173/singleselectlist-trouble-with-customview-for-one-row-onclicklistener)  I have just answrered something like that. I hope it will give you a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

There are two easy solution for this problem:

1. Remove the LinearLayout and user only CheckedTextView (Yes, it is possible). So the main element of the layout is checkable and it will be marked.
2. If your minSDK is 11 of above, customize the android:checkMarke and set a state to Activated. Here is an example:

Example code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_selected"/>  
   <item android:state_activated="false" android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_deselected" />  
   <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_deselected" />  
   <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_selected" /> 
</selector>
```

Source: http://www.jiahaoliuliu.com/2013/08/customizing-checkbox-in-android.html

The middle level solution is customize the onItemClickListener of the list view, as shown on this code:
https://github.com/jiahaoliuliu/CustomizedListRow

The hard but the correct solution is the one proposed by MarvinLab:
http://www.marvinlabs.com/2010/10/29/custom-listview-ability-check-items/

Related issue: [What is the difference between the states selected, checked and activated in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504860/what-is-the-difference-between-the-states-selected-checked-and-activated-in-and)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by the attr `singleLine = true`. If you delete this or replace with `maxLines = 1`, it will work fine. Actually, the status is checked when you click on the item — I think it's an Android bug.