# How to select only one checkbox selected in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm developing an Android application with a `ListView`. Every item in this `ListView` will have a `checkbox`.

I'm trying to uncheck every item when user clicks on one of them. E.g. a `ListView` with two items, **0, 1**.

At this moment 0 is selected and user taps on item 1. I want to deselect item 0.

This is my code. It's inside an `ArrayAdapter`.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(itemLayoutId, parent, false);
    }

    Gate gate = gates.get(position);
    if (gate != null)
    {
        TextView itemText = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.gateNameText);
        if (itemText != null)
            itemText.setText(gate.getName());

        ImageView imageView = 
                (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.gateTypeImage);
        int resId;

        switch (gate.getSelTypeOperation())
        {
            case 0:
                resId = R.drawable.garage;
                break;
            case 1:
                resId = R.drawable.pulse;
                break;
            case 2:
                resId = R.drawable.onoff;
                break;
            default:
                resId = R.drawable.garage;
                break;
        }
        imageView.setImageResource(resId);

        CheckBox checkBox = 
                (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.gateSelectedCheck);
        if (checkBox != null)
        {
            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
            {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked)
                {
                    // Solo hago algo si el nuevo estado es marcado.
                    if (isChecked)
                        for(int i = 0; i < gates.size(); i++)
                        {
                            if (i != position)
                            {
                                Log.v("GatesAdapter", "uncheck: " + position);
                                View view = getView(i, null, null);
                                CheckBox checkBox = 
                                        (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.gateSelectedCheck);
                                checkBox.setChecked(false);
                            }
                        }
                }
            });
            checkBox.setChecked(selectedGateIndex == position);
        }
    }

    return row;
}
```

But, it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it is better if u use RadioButtons in this case.

Comment: Can I use a RadioButtonGroup in a ListView?

Comment: By default no. Check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You need to use listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE) and, u need to make your custom view's row implement checkable.
. Another SO question already - soln is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5612808/735675)

Comment: Actually this is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7329856/735675

Answer (score 1):

Just change your `getview()` method as shown below:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        final Holder holder;
        if (vi == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_customelabel_list, null);
            holder = new Holder();

            holder.txtname = (TextView) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.raw_customlabel_txt_name);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.raw_customlabel_checkbox);
            vi.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (Holder) vi.getTag();
        }

        vi.setTag(holder);
        holder.txtname.setText(strarry[position]);

        holder.checkbox.setId(position);
        holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i = 0; i < strarry.length; i++) {
                    if (v.getId() == i) {
                        checkarry[i] = true;
                        Log.v("check", ""+position);
                    } else {
                        checkarry[i] = false;
                    }
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        if (checkarry[position]) {
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
        }

        return vi;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use these below code it will work fine for you

```
int selected_position =-1
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{


if(selected_position==position)
        {
            CHECKBOX.setChecked(true);

        }
        else
        {
            CHECKBOX.setChecked(false);

        }

            CHECKBOX.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {



                    if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked())
                    {
                        selected_position= position;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        selected_position=-1;
                    }


                    notifyDataSetChanged();


                }
            });
      return view;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use radio buttons. If I see check boxes, I think I may select as many as I want.

Is not solving your issue if you just replace your CheckBox object with a RadioButton in your code?