# Select only one radio button at a time in custom list view, android

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to make a custom list view. Each entry in the list view will have a imageview, a textview and a radiobutton. I finally made the list but now I am having a problem in selecting radio buttons.

What I want is Whenever a user clicks anywhere in an entry then this should set the corresponding radio button and automatically deselect other radio buttons in list.

Here's my code:
bus_item.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imglist_icon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/alaknanda" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtlist_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Alaknanda"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_list"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**BusListActivity.java :-**

```
package com.hpubts50.hpubustrackerserver;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BusListActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bus_list);

        // Setting List Adapter for custom list
        setListAdapter(new MyBusListAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.txtlist_name, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.HPU_Buses)));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Log.e("MYTAG",""+position);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bus_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // Custom Adapter inner class for custom list

    private class MyBusListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public MyBusListAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] strings) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Log.e("MYTAG","one");
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bus_item, parent, false);
            String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.HPU_Buses);
            Log.e("MYTAG","two");

            ImageView imglist_icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imglist_icon);
            TextView txtlist_name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtlist_name);
            RadioButton radio_list = (RadioButton) row.findViewById(R.id.radio_list);
            Log.e("MYTAG","three");

            txtlist_name.setText(items[position]);
            Log.e("MYTAG","four");

            if (items[position].equals("Alakananda")) {
                imglist_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.alaknanda);
            } else if (items[position].equals("Alakananda")) {
                imglist_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.alaknanda);
            }else if (items[position].equals("Chetanya")) {
                imglist_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.chetanya);
            }else if (items[position].equals("Garuda")) {
                imglist_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.garuda);
            }else if (items[position].equals("Nandi")) {
                imglist_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.nandi);
            }else if (items[position].equals("Neela")) {
                imglist_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.neela);
            }
            Log.e("MYTAG","five");

            return row;
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_bus_list.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".BusListActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to use `RadioGroup` to allow items to be selected only once: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use RadioGroup in ListView custom adapter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329856/how-to-use-radiogroup-in-listview-custom-adapter)

Answer (score 12):

You might want to take a look at my piece of work. I'm using a custom adapter as a subclass but what I did can obviously be applied to the list activity.

1. I took an instance of RadioButton "selected" and initially made it null.
2. I implemented onClickListener on each of the radio buttons in getView function
3. Now I'll use "selected" to hold the reference of the "last" radio button that was checked
4. Then I simply uncheck the previous radio button and check the current one
5. Also don't forget to use "selected" to hold the reference of this radio button which was just checked

> ```
> class FolderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
> {
>     ArrayList<File> list;
>     Context context;
>     RadioButton selected=null;
>
>     public FolderAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<File> list)
>     {
>         super(context, resource);
>         this.list = list;
>         this.context = context;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
>     {
>         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_e_row, parent, false);
>         final RadioButton rbFolder = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.rbFolder);
>
>         rbFolder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
>         {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View v)
>             {
>                 if(selected != null)
>                 {
>                     selected.setChecked(false);
>                 }
>
>                 rbFolder.setChecked(true);
>                 selected = rbFolder;
>             }
>         });
>         rbFolder.setText(list.get(position).getName());
>         return view;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public int getCount()
>     {
>         return list.size();
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View vi = convertView;

    if (vi == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_search_engine, null);

    }
    browserImage = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
    browserType = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.browswer_name);
    browserType.setText(browser_names[position]);
    browserImage.setImageResource(image_id[position]);
    check = (RadioButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.check);
    check.setChecked(position == selectedPosition);
    check.setTag(position);
    check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            selectedPosition = (Integer)view.getTag();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    return vi;
}
```

try this might help...for others facing same problem..
selectedPosition = 0 initialize this anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is to do so :

```
ListView l = getListView();
// because you just want a single selection
l.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Then your listview row must implement Checkable, here is how : see here for an explanation -->
[ListView with CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE using CheckedText in a custom view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612600/listview-with-choice-mode-multiple-using-checkedtext-in-a-custom-view)

Also, your question is the same as here : [How to use RadioGroup in ListView custom adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329856/how-to-use-radiogroup-in-listview-custom-adapter)