# How to check only one checkbox at a time in NLevel Listview

Tags: java, android

I'm making NLevel expandable list using listview. I've added checkbox only last level data in list view.

I want to check only one checkbox at a time. Please any one help me!

Here my code

```
@Override
public View getView(final NLevelItem item) {
// .......

final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.check);
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //store checkbox state, note that NLevelItem item might need to be defined with 'final'
        item.setChecked(checkBox.isChecked());

        if(checkBox.isChecked()){
            tempList.add((String) ((SomeObject)childs.getWrappedObject()).getName()+"+"+name);
        }
        else {
            tempList.remove((String) ((SomeObject)childs.getWrappedObject()).getName()+"+"+name);
        }
    }//onClick()
}//setOnClickListener()

//update checkbox state from the corresponding NLevelItem
checkBox.setChecked(item.isChecked());

//.......
}//getView()
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: you can use radio button instead of check box for single selection

Comment: Check This http://stackoverflow.com/a/37907352/3416642

Comment: @SachinShelar Working your above link but my condition is affected  item.setChecked(checkBox.isChecked());

Answer (score 0):

There's `RadioButton` in `RadioGroup` for doing that, why would you want to use checkbox

Comment: I want only checkbox.. No need radiobutton

Comment: then you can declare an int checkOptionId and store the id of checked checkbox in it....when the user checks another checkbox you can uncheck the previous one